# "JsonEOFException: Unexpected end-of-input" when sending a stream to a Rxjava2 endpoint

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2, micronaut, rx-java3

I'm trying to work out how to call to an endpoint that accepts a `@Body` parameter of `Flowable<Integer>`, to subscribe it to process the incoming stream (using Micronaut and the RxJava framework).  I have this controller in Micronaut:

```
@Post(uri = "inner")
@ExecuteOn(TaskExecutors.IO)
HttpResponse inner(@Body Flowable<Integer> template){

    template.subscribe(new Subscriber<Integer>() {
        Subscription subscription

        @Override
        void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {
            subscription = s
            subscription.request(1l)
        }

        @Override
        void onNext(Integer integer) {
            log.info("inner:onNext called")
            log.info("${integer.toString()} - ${System.currentTimeMillis()}")
            subscription.request(1l)
        }

        @Override
        void onError(Throwable t) {
            log.info("inner:onError called")
            t.printStackTrace()
        }

        @Override
        void onComplete() {
            log.info("inner:onComplete called")
        }
    })
    ok()
}
```

Which I'm calling from another endpoint called `/outer` using the code:

```
rxStreamingHttpClient.exchangeStream(HttpRequest.POST("/inner", Flowable.fromIterable([1,2,3,4,5]))).subscribe()
```

So what I'm expecting is that I call the `/outer` endpoint, which in turn calls the `/inner` endpoint and feeds it the Integer stream to process.  This seems to work, but only intermittently - the `/inner` endpoint always gets called, but it will often get somewhat through processing the stream and then call OnError an exception of `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.JsonEOFException: Unexpected end-of-input`.  However it does sometimes complete successfully.  I can't find an example of how to do this - can anyone advise on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working by amending the `inner` endpoint to use blockingSubscribe, so that the outer subscription didn't complete early. Not sure why this scenario isn't gracefully handled, but glad it works now.

```
template.blockingSubscribe(new Subscriber<Integer>() { ....
```